# Drop ID with all NA within a group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have some data prepared using the below code:

```
# # Data Preparation ----------------------
library(lubridate)
start_date <- "2018-10-30 00:00:00"
start_date <- as.POSIXct(start_date, origin="1970-01-01")
dates <- c(start_date)
for(i in 1:287) {
    dates <- c(dates, start_date + minutes(i * 10))
}
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates, origin="1970-01-01")
date_val <- format(dates, '%d-%m-%Y')

weather.forecast.data <- data.frame(dateTime = dates, date = date_val, id = 'GH1', radiation = runif(288))
weather.forecast.data$radiation[(weather.forecast.data$id == 'GH1') & (weather.forecast.data$date == '30-10-2018')] = NA
```

My task is to filter rows from the `weather.forecast.data` where all radiation values are missing for each unique instance of id and date.

I have the code written using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data[, dateid := paste(date, id, sep = "__")]
weather.forecast.data[, is_all_na := all(is.na(radiation)), dateid]
weather.forecast.data = weather.forecast.data[!(is_all_na), !c('dateid', 'is_all_na'), with = FALSE]
```

I am trying to use `dplyr` functions and pipe operations to make it better readable:

```
library(dplyr)
weather.forecast.data %>%
  mutate(dateid = paste(date, id, sep = "__")) %>%
  group_by(dateid) %>%
  summarise(is_all_na = all(is.na(radiation))) %>%
  filter(is_all_na) %>%
  select(dateid)
```

I am able to retrieve the `id` with all missing. But, I am unable to remove the `id` from the original data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to `paste` columns together, you can `group_by` multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)

weather.forecast.data %>%
   group_by(date, id) %>%
   filter(!all(is.na(radiation)))
```

This will drop the rows where `all` the `radiation` is `NA` for each `date` and `id`.

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. I guess I have complicated it in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Also, can you help me with the code to check if the morning part of day (06 to 18 hours) is missing, drop the ID from the data?

Comment: @KartheekPalepu This looks like a completely new question so I would suggest you to ask this as a new questions separately.

Comment: Added the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060304/drop-id-with-na-in-a-conditional-group

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options using `data.table`:

1) Using `.I` to subset the original dataset

```
setDT(weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data[
    weather.forecast.data[, .I[sum(is.na(radiation))!=.N], by=.(date, id)]$V1
]
```

2) Using anti-join

```
setDT(weather.forecast.data)[
    !weather.forecast.data[, all(is.na(radiation)), by=.(date, id)][(V1)],
    on=.(date, id)]
```

output (hopefully this is what OP is looking for since no sample output was posted):

```
                dateTime       date  id  radiation
  1: 2018-10-31 00:00:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.01794694
  2: 2018-10-31 00:10:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.55482429
  3: 2018-10-31 00:20:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.31422673
  4: 2018-10-31 00:30:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.43734765
  5: 2018-10-31 00:40:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.29053698
 ---                                              
140: 2018-10-31 23:10:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.56968294
141: 2018-10-31 23:20:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.26055891
142: 2018-10-31 23:30:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.15140244
143: 2018-10-31 23:40:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.59824054
144: 2018-10-31 23:50:00 31-10-2018 GH1 0.55101842
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Always good to learn something new :-)