# Drop ID with NA in a conditional group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Extending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059075/drop-id-with-all-na-within-a-group) question:

I have some data prepared using the below code:

```
# # Data Preparation ----------------------
library(lubridate)
start_date <- "2018-10-30 00:00:00"
start_date <- as.POSIXct(start_date, origin="1970-01-01")
dates <- c(start_date)
for(i in 1:287) {
    dates <- c(dates, start_date + minutes(i * 10))
}
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates, origin="1970-01-01")
date_val <- format(dates, '%d-%m-%Y')

weather.forecast.data <- data.frame(dateTime = dates, date = date_val)
weather.forecast.data <- rbind(weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data$id <- c(rep('GH1', 288), rep('GH2', 288), rep('GH3', 288), rep('GH4', 288))
weather.forecast.data$radiation <- round(runif(nrow(weather.forecast.data)), 2)

weather.forecast.data$hour <- as.integer(format(weather.forecast.data$dateTime, '%H'))
weather.forecast.data$day_night <- ifelse(weather.forecast.data$hour < 6, 'night', ifelse(weather.forecast.data$hour < 19, 'day', 'night'))

# # GH2: Total Morning missing # #
weather.forecast.data$radiation[(weather.forecast.data$id == 'GH2') & (weather.forecast.data$date == '30-10-2018') & (weather.forecast.data$day_night == 'day')] = NA
weather.forecast.data$hour <- NULL
weather.forecast.data$day_night <- NULL
```

My task is to remove ids from the weather.forecast.data where for each id and each date, morning half (06 hours to 18 hours), the radiation values are missing (NA) using `dplyr` in `R`.

I want to eliminate rows for a given `id` and `date` which has the entire morning `radiation` value as missing. i.e. if an id for a `date` has morning `radiation` missing. I drop all the rows with that particular `id` and `date`. So, we drop all the 144 records because its morning has radiation missing.

We can see that `GH2` has entire morning radiation missing on date `30-10-2018`. We therefore drop all 144 records with `id == 'GH2'` and `date = '30-10-2018'`.

```
setDT(weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data[, sum(is.na(radiation)), .(id, date)]
    id       date V1
1: GH1 30-10-2018  0
2: GH1 31-10-2018  0
3: GH2 30-10-2018 78
4: GH2 31-10-2018  0
5: GH3 30-10-2018  0
6: GH3 31-10-2018  0
7: GH4 30-10-2018  0
8: GH4 31-10-2018  0
```

I have the code using `data.table`:

```
setDT(weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data[, hour:= hour(dateTime)]
weather.forecast.data[, day_night:=c("night", "day")[(6 <= hour & hour < 19) + 1L]]
weather.forecast.data[, date_id := paste(date, id, sep = "__")]
weather.forecast.data[, all_is_na := all(is.na(radiation)), .(date_id, day_night)]
weather.forecast.data[!(date_id %in% unique(weather.forecast.data[(all_is_na == TRUE) & (day_night == 'day'), date_id]))]
```

I need the code using `dplyr` and I have tried the following. It is dropping many rows than required:

```
library(dplyr)
weather.forecast.data <- weather.forecast.data %>%
    mutate(hour = as.integer(format(dateTime, '%H'))) %>%
    mutate(day_night = ifelse(hour < 6, 'night', ifelse(hour < 19, 'day', 'night'))) %>%
    group_by(date, day_night, id) %>%
    filter((!all(is.na(radiation))) & (day_night == 'day')) %>%
    select (-c(hour, day_night)) %>%
    as.data.frame
```

**Note**: Output should return the data by dropping the rows where `id = 'GH2'` and `date = '30-10-2018'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are complicating a bit. The following code does what you describe in the question.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

weather.forecast.data %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(dateTime),
         day_night = c("night", "day")[(6 <= hour & hour < 19) + 1L]) %>%
  group_by(date, id) %>%
  mutate(delete = all(!(is.na(radiation) & day_night == "day"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(delete) %>%
  select(-hour, -day_night, -delete) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> df1
```

See if it worked giving the expected 144 deleted rows.

```
nrow(weather.forecast.data) - nrow(df1)
#[1] 144
```

**Data.**

I repost the data generation code, simplified in two places and with a call to `set.seed`.

```
set.seed(4192)

start_date <- "2018-10-30 00:00:00"
start_date <- as.POSIXct(start_date, origin="1970-01-01")
dates <- start_date + minutes(0:287 * 10)
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates, origin="1970-01-01")
date_val <- format(dates, '%d-%m-%Y')

weather.forecast.data <- data.frame(dateTime = dates, date = date_val)
weather.forecast.data <- rbind(weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data, weather.forecast.data)
weather.forecast.data$id <- c(rep('GH1', 288), rep('GH2', 288), rep('GH3', 288), rep('GH4', 288))
weather.forecast.data$radiation <- round(runif(nrow(weather.forecast.data)), 2)

weather.forecast.data$hour <- hour(weather.forecast.data$dateTime)
weather.forecast.data$day_night <- ifelse(weather.forecast.data$hour < 6, 'night', ifelse(weather.forecast.data$hour < 19, 'day', 'night'))

# # GH2: Total Morning missing # #
weather.forecast.data$radiation[(weather.forecast.data$id == 'GH2') & (weather.forecast.data$date == '30-10-2018') & (weather.forecast.data$day_night == 'day')] = NA
weather.forecast.data$hour <- NULL
weather.forecast.data$day_night <- NULL
```

Comment: Your code is not dropping any records. Ideally it should drop the records for `id = GH2` and `date = 30-10-2018` as it has the entire morning radiation missing.

Comment: @KartheekPalepu Sorry, you are right. I had `c("night", "day")` reversed. Bug corrected.

Comment: Still the code isn't dropping any records. Also, I am worried that you are grouping by date and id and checking if the entire group is NA. I only need the day part to be NA. (If this helps to update your code). I need the entire rows that has id = GH2 and date = 30-10-2018 to be dropped as the entire morning radiation data for that group is missing.

Comment: @KartheekPalepu I believe that this time you are wrong, my code is dropping 78 records. If you assign the pipe to `df1` and compare the dims of `weather.forecast.data` and of `df1` there's a difference equal to `sum(weather.forecast.data$id == 'GH2' & weather.forecast.data$date == '30-10-2018' & is.na(weather.forecast.data$radiation))`.

Comment: Apologies, It is dropping 78 records. It needs to eliminate all 144 records for that id and the date. (where each id has 144 records for each date)

Comment: @KartheekPalepu Now I am puzzled. The 144 records include `day_night == "night"`. Do you want to eliminate those too? If so there is no need to `mutate`.

Comment: May be if I set the context It will help you. I want to eliminate rows for a given `id` and `date` which has the entire morning radiation value as missing. i.e. if an `id` for a `date` has morning radiation missing. I drop all the rows with that particular `id` and `date`. So, we drop all the 144 records because its morning has radiation missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering for rows that only contain "day" in the **day_night** column. If I understood you correctly you want the following:

```
    library(dplyr)
    weather.forecast.data <- weather.forecast.data %>%
      mutate(hour = as.integer(format(dateTime, '%H'))) %>%
      mutate(day_night = ifelse(hour < 6, 'night', ifelse(hour < 19, 'day', 
                                                         'night'))) %>%
      group_by(date, day_night, id) %>%
      filter((!(all(is.na(radiation))) & (day_night == 'day'))) %>%
      select (-c(hour, day_night)) %>%
      as.data.frame
```

This would remove all IDs that have all NAs during the day.

Comment: the code you provided is dropping all night data for all the ids. Ideally it only needs to drop the data points for `id = GH2` and `date = 30-10-2018`.

Comment: You're right. You have to remove the **all** in the **filter** call and the **day_night** in the **group_by** as Rui Barradas said in his answer.